# Power Pivot KPI

Tags: excel, powerpivot, kpi

I'm preparing for the Microsoft Excel exam and I found a problem about KPI in Power Pivot.

The question is:

You have a KPI named Goal that calculates the sales from the previous year and multiplies the sales by 1.1. You need to modify Goal to multiply the sales from the previous year by 1.15.

What should you do?

A. From Power Pivot, modify the measure

B. From Power Pivot, create a new calculated column, and then modify the KPI

C. From the properties of the KPI, modify the absolute value

D. From the properties of the KPI, modify the KPI base field

I'm thinking of A, modifying the measure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a KPI named Goal that calculates the sales from the previous year and multiplies the sales by 1.1. You need to modify Goal to multiply the sales from the previous year by 1.15.

Its A. Modify the measure